# A way to perform math operations on a logging metric field in Stackdriver?

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I have created a log-based metric on Google Cloud against an AppEngine log.  The metric scans for a specific URL and pulls out a field from that URL.

For example:
http://www.example.com/page.html?type=a
http://www.example.com/page.html?type=b

In Stackdriver, I can create the chart that shows the two metrics (types A and B) broken down by type at the same time.

What I am hoping to create is a chart that shows the ratio between types A and B.  Is something like that possible? to perform any arithmetic operation on the results of a time interval?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this feature is not available in Stack Driver at the moment, however I have created a request to Google internal teams in order to study the possibility to add it.
You can follow up that request on that link: https://issuetracker.google.com/72304083

regards